# Referencing ajax calls to multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i have to two pages in jquery mobile and in each of the pages is a `div` called `content` and inside the divs i call external pages into it by means of ajax. for `"page1"` the call works perfectly but for `"page2"` the call isn't working. though the div in "page2" is having the same name as that of `"page1"`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>


<script language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    setInterval(function() {
    $('#content').load('total.asp');
    }, 3000); 
    });

</script>

</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Page 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <table width="311" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
      <tr>
        <td width="77">Content</td>
        <td width="102"><div id="content"></div></td>
        <td width="102"><a href="#page2">Go to Page 2</a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Footer</h4>
  </div>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Page 2</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <table width="320" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
      <tr>
        <td width="77">Content</td>
        <td width="102"><div id="content"></div></td>
        <td width="102"><a href="#page1">Go to Page 1</a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Footer</h4>
  </div>
</div>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID has to be unique. try changing `id="content"` to `class="content"` and then try the below code

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    setInterval(function() {
        $('.content').load('total.asp');
    }, 3000); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try using:

```
$("div").find("[data-role='content']").load('total.asp');
```

because you have given it as data attribute. you can better use class if you have multiple id with same name in that case it will be:

```
$(".content").load('total.asp');
```